# cloud texture browser throws python exception in 2.93

Tags: add-on

Has anyone encountered the following error when entering the Cloud Texture Browser (blender_cloud-1.19.addon) in v 2.93?

[image]

I also see in the console during startup:

> WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v293\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1505 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '0' matches no enum in 'BlenderCloudProjectGroup', '', 'project'

My login and other features (share screenshot, synch) work fine.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem. But no solution for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, the add-on has been updated to version 1.23 and that works with Blender 2.93